# Solve a matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-equations, positive-definite

$A$ is a $n\times n$ positive-definite matrix and $x$ is a $n$-vector.

$\overrightarrow{0}=(0,0,...,0)^t$ and $\overrightarrow{1}=(1,1,...,1)^t$

How to solve the inequalities system$\overrightarrow{0}\leq Ax\leq \overrightarrow{1}$, i.e, there are $n$ inequalities and the $i$-th one is:

$0 \leq A_{i1} x_1$+$A_{i2} x_2$+....+$A_{in} x_n \leq 1$.

Many thanks for the helps.

Comment: What do you mean with $\leq$ for vectors?